# Public Twitter timeline in UITableView - iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, ios7

I am writing an app for a client and I need to display their twitter timeline in a table view. I need to do this without needing the user to be signed in to a twitter account on their phone. The only ways to display a timeline that I have been able to find so far require that the phone has a signed in twitter account. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't retrieve Twitter accounts of any user in an iPhone without acquiring permission from the user.

**But** if you want to retrieve public posts of a Twitter user whose **username** you have already known, you can do it using the Twitter API.

Also I would like to mention that `AFNetworking` networking library has a sample usage of Twitter public timeline. You can find it at: `https://github.com/AFNetworking`.

Comment: Getting public posts of a known username is exactly what I want to do. Can you provide more detail for this?

Comment: As i said, latest version of `AFNetworking` include an implementation for what you are looking for. Of course that implementation uses `AFNetworking` library, but I think you can get the essence of it from the code.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter API since v1.1 requires authentication for each request. So the only way to get user timeline is to implement OAuth, or use integrated iOS Twitter API.